# using Runtime.exec() in Java

Tags: java, path, exec

What do you have to do in Java to get the Runtime.exec() to run a program that is on the path? I'm trying to run gpsbabel which I have put into the path (/usr/local/bin).

```
public class GpxLib {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {
            Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process p = r.exec("gpsbabel -i garmin -f usb: -o gpx -F -");
            InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            while (true)
            {
                String s = br.readLine();
                if (s == null)
                    break;
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            br.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whatever you do, you must read [this](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html). No one should use `Runtime.exec()` without having read it.

Comment: What error/behaviour are you seeing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will inherit the path from the Java process. So whatever environment the Java process has, the spawned process will have as well. Here's how to check the environment:

```
Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
     System.out.format("%s=%s%n", envName, env.get(envName));
}
```

Have you set the `PATH` *and* exported it ? If you don't export it, then it's not available to subprocesses.

Additionally, you *must* consume stdout and stderr concurrently, to prevent blocking. Otherwise stuff will work in some circumstances, then your spawned process will output a different quantity of data and everything will grind to a halt.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882772/capturing-stdout-when-calling-runtime-exec/882795#882795) for more details.

Comment: I haven't set the path at all, anywhere. It is whatever the default path is for Eclipse and for bash.

Comment: The path will be set per user. You may want to add the path entry for that executable in your .bashrc (and perhaps login again if you're launching Eclipse from the toolbar or similar)

Comment: I think the *real* solution is to specify the complete path to the binary, however, so that your program isn't environment dependent, and then make that a configuration item. That's usually my *strategic* approach.

Comment: agreed, I suppose the better way is to use a .properties file.... I just hate having to run java programs like "java -Dsome.ugly.variable=/usr/local/bin/gpsbabel -jar myjar.jar"

Comment: ...and I just want to put gpsbabel someplace appropriate so I can access it on the path. I asked a question somewhere (dammit, can't find which question, i thought it was on superuser or serverfault) and /usr/local/bin was the recommended place.

Answer (score 4):

I added a call to `System.out.println(System.getenv("PATH"));` which only prints out

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

so for some reason /usr/local/bin doesn't show up. Looks like this is a MacOSX question or an Eclipse question, not a Java question. **edit:** asked [this question on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/28344/path-env-variable-on-mac-osx-and-or-eclipse) instead.

Comment: See my modified answer re. variables and exporting

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution:

```
ProcessBuilder proc = new ProcessBuilder("<Directory PAth>" + "Executable.exe");
proc.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
proc.directory(fi); //fi = the output directory path
proc.start();
```

is the path where program\application's excutable is located e.g "C:\MyProg\"

Comment: anybody can explain what is wrong with this code? I have Tested successfully by calling a C++ console application in it.