# Baffling Failure to Call External Executable From Within Java Program

Tags: java, windows, executable, volume

All right, I've hit a bug that has simply confused the bejeebus out of me.  I'm looking for ideas about what it could be that I can investigate, because right now, I got nothing.  It goes something like this:

I have a standalone Java application that occasionally needs to twiddle the Line-In volume of the computer it's running on (a WinXP machine).  It does this by calling a pair of external executables (written in VB6*) that can get and set various component volumes.  (They can handle Line-In, Mic, Wave, CD, and the master volume control.)

There are several hundred units in the field, running on hardware (Dell machines) that my company provided and controls.  At least several dozen clients are using this feature, and it works perfectly -- except for one instance.

For this one troublemaking machine, it simply doesn't work.  I watch the volume sliders when the app is running, and when the volume is supposed to drop, they stay put.  When I check the app's log file, it throws no errors, *and* appears to be executing the code that drops the volume.  When I run the executables from the command line, they work perfectly.

I can't vouch for this machine being 100% identical to all the ones that are behaving properly, but we've been buying the same line of Dells for quite some time now; at a bare minimum, it's very, very similar.

So, turning my confusion into a bullet list:

- If I'm doing something stupid in the Java code (i.e., not clearing my STDOUT/STDERR buffers), why is it only an issue on this machine?
- If there's something broken in the VB6 executables, why do they work on every other machine **and** on this machine from the command line?
- If there's some sort of hardware oddity on this machine, what sort of oddity could cause the volume control executables to fail **only** when called from within a Java application?

I am very confused.  I do not like being confused.  Anybody have any suggestions that may lead to my enlightenment?**

-* -- I know, I know, VB6, 1998 called and they want their obsolescent proprietary bug generator back, etc.  Wasn't my decision.  But the code works.  Usually.

-** -- Insert Buddhism joke here.

---

**Update Edit:**  Customer service may have stumbled onto something; it may be something to do with client configuration settings in the database.  New evidence suggests that either something's misconfigured for that client or my software is doing something stupid in response to a specific configuration.  And the problem may be more widespread than we thought, due to this particular feature not being as commonly used as I thought.

Responding to the comments:

- Debugger:  Theoretically possible, but looks like a massive headache given our setup.
- High Verbosity Logging, Java:  Good idea this, particularly given than the problem may be more widespread than I originally believed.  Time to start revisiting some assumptions.  And possibly clubbing them.  Like baby seals.
- High Verbosity Logging, VB6:  A possibility; will need to be rolled-into the high-verbosity Java logging to trap the output, since my VB6-fu is so pitiably weak I don't know how to output text to a file.  But, yeah, knowing whether or not the script is even getting called would be valuable.
- Window Event Viewer:  Not familiar with this tool.  May have to correct that.
- PATH problem:  Doesn't feel likely; the Java code constructs a relative path to the executable that doesn't look like it's relying on any environment variables.

My thanks for the suggestions people have provided; at the very least, you've gotten my brain moving in directions that feel promising.

---

**Solution Edit:**  And the winner is ... That's Not A Bug, That's A Feature!  A feature gone horribly, horribly wrong.  A feature that will now be neutered so as to stop bothering us.

A batch of invalid assumptions kept me from seeing it sooner, not the least of which was "I don't need to tool the code with more debug statements -- the statements already in there are telling me all I need to know!"  DaDaDom, if you'd like to turn your comment into an answer, there's a shiny checkmark in it for you.

Thanks to everybody who chimed in with a suggestion.  Now if you'll excuse me, my head is late for a meeting with my desk.

Comment: Can you create a version of the software with verbose logging or could you even debug the code? At least then you can tell if it's in the java or the VB part.

Comment: Is there anything in the Windows Event Viewer? Have you tried running the app using a debugger?

Comment: Put some logging into vb app, line by line. You'd see if it executes at all and where it fails, if.

Comment: So you have sorted out that the call is not being received at the VB executable end when invoked via Java? Sounds like a PATH issue to me. How is your Java program invoked, .bat/.cmd or Web Start? You can also try renaming the executables (and the call offcourse)

Comment: @DaDaDom:  If you'd like to turn that (perfectly common-sense) comment into an answer, I have a checkmark with your name on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here goes an answer:
Can you create a version of the software with verbose logging or could you even debug the code? At least then you can tell if it's in the java or the VB part.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmmm. I've been told that executing programs from Java is either easy or hard. The easy part is starting them up. The hard part is dealing with the I/O streams (see [my earlier question on using Runtime.exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319286/using-runtime-exec-in-java)). Maybe the VB program is doing or expecting something weird on these particular machines that the Java code isn't working with properly.

---

edit: I also found a link to [Jakarta Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/):

> **Rationale**
>
> Executing external processes from Java is a well-known problem area. It is inheriently platform dependent and requires the developer to know and test for platform specific behaviors, for example using cmd.exe on Windows or limited buffer sizes causing deadlocks. The JRE support for this is very limited, albeit better with the new Java SE 1.5 ProcessBuilder class.
>
> Reliably executing external processes can also require knowledge of the environment variables before or after the command is executed. In J2SE 1.1-1.4 there is not support for this, since the method, System.getenv(), for retriving environment variables is deprecated.
>
> There are currently several different libraries that for their own purposes have implemented frameworks around Runtime.exec() to handle the various issues outlined above. The proposed project should aim at coordinating and learning from these initatives to create and maintain a simple, reusable and well-tested package. Since some of the more problematic platforms are not readily available, it is my hope that the broad Apache community can be a great help.

Comment: The VB call is so straightforward that it's hard to imagine what environment variables it's looking for that are messed-up.  Which doesn't mean you're wrong, of course.  :-)  As for Jakarta Commons Exec, might be worth a try, thanks.

Comment: Thanks.  And +1 for pointing me at the Jakarta Commons Exec; don't think it's going to be my solution here, but another tool in the box is always welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the possibility that the authenticated user may not have permission to edit volume settings on the workstation? Does the program run correctly if you run as an 'Administrator'?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't it -- but +1 for a bloody clever idea that would fit the described behavior perfectly.