# Eclipse CDT - using objdump in Windows

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

The Eclipse CDT Binary Parser '**GNU Elf Parser**' is having trouble on my Eclipse install on Windows.

- All works fine on linux install

**Problem**

I have a compiled ELF in the GNU ELF 32 format. When I attempt to view this with the GNU Elf Parser, I get:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "objdump": Launching failed
at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.spawner.Spawner.exec(Spawner.java:347)
...
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

**Deubg**

Of course, this just means the CDT-plugins can't find objdump.

- The ELF tested opens correctly in a linux-eclipse-cdt install
- Say my *objdump* is located at '**C:\binutils\bin**'
- How the heck do you setup Eclipse's CLASSPATH to search there?

I've tried several things, from editing my system PATH, or CLASSPATH. I've also tried setting Workspace & C/C++ Build/Env settings. Nothing has worked.

**Question**

How the heck do you get this to work?

**Edit - Basic Solution**

Feel kind of silly, but to solve you just need to install MinGW and add C:/MinGW/bin to PATH. Then restart Eclipse.

- I'm producing my own Eclipse distro with our own in-house toolchain & objdump versions, thus the mixup!
- I've tried several other ways to get this to work (so I can eventually use our own objdump instance, but no luck!

**Basic Solution Notes:**

1. All you need from C:\MinGW\bin to make this work is:

   - objdump.exe
   - addr2line.exe
   - c++filt.exe
   - libgcc_s_sw2-1.dll
   - zlib1.dll

So if you move these to, say **C:\myGnuBinUtils** and add that to your system **PATH** (not some eclipse-setting, the actual path), then this works too.

- these files are 24MB total; MinGW is 715MB...

Does anyone know how to achieve the same result with out HAVING to modify system PATH?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need an "ObjDump" Java wrapper.  For example:

- https://code.google.com/p/cdtplugin/source/browse/trunk/org.eclipse.cdt.core/src/org/eclipse/cdt/utils/Objdump.java?r=5

"CLASSPATH" is Java-only: it won't affect running a non-Java .exe

Java exec() will use the system PATH of your Java VM.  You can, however, modify it at runtime.  For example:

[using Runtime.exec() in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319286/using-runtime-exec-in-java)

```
ProcessBuilder proc = new ProcessBuilder("<Directory PAth>" + "Executable.exe");
proc.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
proc.directory(fi); //fi = the output directory path
proc.start();
```

Comment: thanks for the link; it appears they've hardcoded 'objdump' to the source code!