# create process error 2 while encrypting file using gpg

Tags: encryption, gnupg

I'm trying to encrypt file.

Here is my command.

```
"gpg --yes --batch --cipher-algo AES256 --passphrase abcd123 --output "+"E:/Softwares"+"/" +"logfile"+".gpg --symmetric --cipher-algo AES256 "+"E:/Softwares/logfile.txt"
```

But am getting error like this:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "gpg": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
```

Please anyone can help me what's going on?

I've used this command earlier to do encryption as well. but this time its giving problem.

Thanks !!

Comment: This sounds as if `gpg` is not on your `$PATH` any more.

Comment: @JensErat Thanks jens !! Is there any way I could make it work jen ?

Comment: If you know the path of GnuPG is fixed, I'd go for absolute paths, otherwise make sure to add the path GnuPG is installed to to your path variable. How to do this is for example explained in http://stackoverflow.com/q/1319286/695343