# calling an exe file inside jar

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I am trying to call the "dspdf.exe" inside the jar file where this smartpdf class exists. I plan to extract it to a temp location and delete when program ends. However this doesn't seem to work, any help will be appreciated.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.omg.CORBA.portable.InputStream;


public class smartpdf {
 static String url="";
 static String output="output.pdf";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
 gui mygui = new gui();//gui will call the generate function when user selects
}

 public static void generate() throws IOException{
  InputStream src = (InputStream) smartpdf.class.getResource("dspdf.exe").openStream();
  File exeTempFile = File.createTempFile("dspdf", ".exe");
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(exeTempFile);
  byte[] temp = new byte[32768];
  int rc;
  while((rc = src.read(temp)) > 0)
      out.write(temp, 0, rc);
  src.close();
  out.close();
  exeTempFile.deleteOnExit();
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(exeTempFile.toString()+" "+url+" "+output  );
  //Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dspdf "+url+" "+output);
 }

}
```

EDIT:
The error that I am getting:

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
der.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnecti
on$JarURLInputStream cannot be cast to org.omg.CORBA.portable.InputStream
        at smartpdf.generate(smartpdf.java:18)
        at smartpdf.main(smartpdf.java:14)
        ... 5 more
```

Comment: Help us to help you. "Doesn't seem to work" could mean any number of things. Can you provide some more information?

Comment: sorry I have editted the question to show the error I am getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the wrong InputStream. Change it to java.io.InputStream.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use `org.omg.CORBA.portable.InputStream` instead of a java.io.BufferedInputStream`
with as parameters the inputstream from the resource. I mean this:

```
BufferedInputStream inputstream = new BufferedInputStream(smartpdf.class.getResourceAsStream(...));
```

The same for your fileoutput stream: BufferedOutputStream

Don't use

```
class.getResource(...).openStream();
```

but use

```
class.getResourceAsStream(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note *also* (once you've resolved the `InputStream` issue) that you should be consuming your spawned process stdout and stderr, otherwise the spawned process may block. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882772/capturing-stdout-when-calling-runtime-exec/882795#882795) for more details.