# Porting a Bash Script to Java

Tags: java, bash

I'm attempting to emulate the functionality of the bash shell script below using a Process or ProcessBuilder object in Java. It's not 100% clear to me how I do the redirection for standard-in. How can I accomplish this?

```
#
#  Redirect shell echo command from standard output to file
#  This will construct the input file
# 
exec 1> $STDIN
echo -e "$NFILE\n$GFILE\n$INPUT\n$OUTPUT\n$CAX"
exec 1>&-

#
#  Run executable redirecting standard in as the input file and output to a log file
#
"$EXE" < $STDIN >& $LOG
```

Comment: why `exec 1> $STDIN` ? Why not just  `echo -e "..." > $STDIN`

Comment: @mobrule Not sure. I inherited the script. What does exec 1 do differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Process](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) object streams are misleadingly named. You need to write to the [OutputStream](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) of the Process object.

From the doc:

> All its standard io (i.e. stdin,
>   stdout, stderr) operations will be
>   redirected to the parent process
>   through three streams
>   (Process.getOutputStream(),
>   Process.getInputStream(),
>   Process.getErrorStream()).

You also have to consume the process output and standard error *concurrently*, otherwise buffers will fill up and the process will block. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882772/capturing-stdout-when-calling-runtime-exec/882795#882795) for more information.