# Advantages of using JNA over process execution

Tags: java, linux, exec, jna

I have a project that currently executes many external programs using `java.lang.Process`. Assuming that their functionality is also available in native library form, what would be the advantages of executing said library functions using [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/) instead?

The process executions are fairly heavy - they take a few seconds to complete. Am I correct in thinking that performance gains would be minimal?

Comment: This is one of those questions that just leaves me scratching my head, because it would be so easy to benchmark for oneself.

Comment: To investigate this requires a time commitment. Given that SO users may already have some real world experience of using JNA I am hoping to determine whether performing such a benchmark is worthy of the effort. For instance - perhaps I have missed something obvious re: JNA and it would in fact be a pointless exercise even benchmarking it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find this helpful: [Execute native code via JNI/DLL or EXE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556093/execute-native-code-via-jni-dll-or-exe)

We went with native execution.  As per the accepted answer, there is less risk of memory leaks and it's easy to restart the native process as needed.