# starting vlc player in java

Tags: java, runtime, inputstream

I tried to start vlc player in Java, but somehow it did not word.
Any other Prog I tried worked.
Plz have a look at my code:

```
 try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("K:\\...\\vlc.exe");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
```

Where is the problem starting videoLAN Player?

Comment: Perhaps try rephrasing your question.  http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise

Answer (score 1):

The fact remains, you have an error and you don't know what it is. I second the advice to properly connect up (at least!) the `stderr` stream with a listening thread so you'll see the error message the program is throwing at you.

Comment: The correct steps to follow are available at http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=4 . See listing 4.5 for redirecting the out/err streams.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if the path is valid (exists + is it a file)
2. Use the more readable and portable path-notation which uses slashes
3. You must read out the stderr and stdout streams of the started process else it will hang when the OS-specific bufffer for it is filled

Javacode:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Test {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Test("K:/Programms/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc.exe");
  }

  public Test(String path) {
    File f = new File(path);
    if (!(f.exists()&&f.isFile())) {
      System.out.println("Incorrect path or not a file");
      return;
    }
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
      Process proc = rt.exec(path);
      StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new StreamGobbler(proc.getErrorStream(), false);
      StreamGobbler outputGobbler = new StreamGobbler(proc.getInputStream(), false);
      errorGobbler.start();
      outputGobbler.start();
      System.out.println("\n"+proc.waitFor());
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      ioe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
      ie.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  class StreamGobbler extends Thread {
    InputStream is;
    boolean discard;
    StreamGobbler(InputStream is, boolean discard) {
      this.is = is;
      this.discard = discard;
    }

    public void run() {
      try {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line=null;
        while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
          if(!discard)
            System.out.println(line);    
        }
      catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();  
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check ensure various things.

1. does that file exists ([File.exists()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29)). In particular that treble dot (...) looks wrong. (or is it an ellipsis and you've just removed the path for brevity ?)
2. is it executable ?
3. you need to capture stdout/stderr from the process *concurrently*, or you run the risk of the process blocking. More info with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882772/capturing-stdout-when-calling-runtime-exec/882795#882795).

Comment: ... is only my path. In my real project there is \\Programms\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\

I don't think, I have to check weather the File exists or not, cause I will only start the Programm without any File.

videoLAN Playe 1.0.x works! 0.9.x not...

Answer (score 0):

Actually you made a mistake in your code,exec() method of Runtime class returns java.lang.Process so you should take a return type in your code so try this code...........

```
 try {
        process ps=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("K:\\...\\vlc.exe");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
```