# Java program to run my other program in Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu

Getting insight from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066967/running-other-programs-from-java), I need to have a java program which should run my other program (a C++ program) with some arguments, in Ubuntu, if it is not already running  (I need to check if it is already running using `ps -A | grep 'test'` to see if the result is null). The command to run my desired program looks like this: `./src/test -w -b -f tracefiles/trace111.txt -z`. How can I do this, no matter what directory my java program is currently in? Unfortunately my java program shows this error: `No such file or directory` while if I run the same command from terminal from the same directory of my Java class file, it runs it.

Here is my simple code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class JavaRunCommand {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String s = "./../../../Downloads/yse.wzt/src/yse4 -w -b -f ../../../Downloads/yse.wzt/tracefiles/capacity.10MbpsUP_1MbpsDown_400RTT_PER_0.0001.txt -z -at=eth0 -an=eth1";

        try {

            // run the Unix "ps -ef" command
            // using the Runtime exec method:
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(s);

            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    p.getInputStream()));

            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    p.getErrorStream()));

            // read the output from the command
            System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

            // read any errors from the attempted command
            System.out
                    .println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
            while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

            System.exit(0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("exception happened - here's what I know: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the JAVA bin direction to your PATH variable.  Edit the .bashrc in your home directory and add the following line:

```
export PATH=/path/to/java/bin:$PATH
```

You'll need to 'source' your .bashrc file or restart your terminal for the path to take effect.  In your home directory type:

```
source .bashrc
```

More information on setting environment variables on Ubuntu is available here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Persistent_environment_variables.

You can confirm whether the PATH assignment was correct with `echo $PATH` or simply typing `javac` from a directory other than the java/bin directory.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the real question.

Comment: The problem is JAVA isn't on the path, so the program is failing.  How is that not relevant?

Comment: Actually these are basics! It's already done.

Comment: Post an answer how did you solve it.

Comment: @LukePeterson Well, Java not being on the path is not the problem...the problem is that my Java program can not find/run the other program.

Comment: Ok thanks, perhaps add that to your original question.