# Running command from java produces empty output

Tags: java, command-line, processbuilder

I need to run the below comand using java but it is running fine in terminal as

svn list http://192.168.0.19/svn/cc/Branch/Jobs/tt/jobs/ --username prasadh --password prasadh2k > output.txt

But when running the same via process builder it is returning empty result.

My code:

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "C:\\Users\\dev112\\output", "svn", "list", "http://192.168.0.19/svn/cadgraf/Branch/Jobs/T0003SATHYABAMAT/Completedjobs", "--username", "prasadh", "--password", "prasadh2k", ">", "output.txt");
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    try {
        Process p = pb.start();
        new Thread(new InputConsumerforImageMagick.InputConsumer(p.getInputStream())).start();
        try {
            System.err.println("Exited with: " + p.getErrorStream());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AddImage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AddImage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: did you mean to drop the `/c` from "cmd /C command to run"  I suggest you try running the whole command on the command line with the `cmd`  Most likely you are getting an error and since you are ignoring the error stream you can't see it.

Comment: No am trying to write the output in a text file but it is creating text file but not writing any value ino it.

Comment: In that case you most likely need the `/C`

Comment: Why go through `cmd` at all?

Comment: When i try like this   "ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/C:\\Users\\dev112\\output", "svn", "list", "http://192.168.0.19/svn/cadgraf/Branch/Jobs/T0003SATHYABAMAT/Completedjobs", "--username", "prasadh", "--password", "prasadh2k", ">", "output.txt");" output file is not created

Comment: @PrasathBala: Try `"cmd", "/c", "C:\\..."`.

Comment: @  Aaron Digulla:  Again it is creating empty file only of 0 kb

Comment: @PrasathBala: Sorry, that should have been `"cmd", "/c", "svn list ..."`

Comment: Check this answer [Running external command with output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46312819/2110245)

Comment: Check this answer [Running processBuilder with output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46312819/2110245)

Answer (score 0):

Don't go through `cmd`. Just run the command directly:

```
final Path cwd = Paths.get("c:\\Users\\dev112\\output");
Files.createDirectories(cwd);
final Path outfile = cwd.resolve("output.txt");

final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("svn", "list",
    "http://192.168.0.19/svn/cadgraf/Branch/Jobs/T0003SATHYABAMAT/Completedjobs",
    "--username", "prasadh", "--password", "prasadh2k");

pb.directory(cwd.toFile());
pb.redirectOutput(outfile.toFile());

final int retcode = pb.start().waitFor();
```

What is more, why do you get the process' standard output if you output to a file? Do one or the other, not both. If you output to a file then read the contents of that file after the command is executed.

The sample above outputs to a file; just open a stream to that file afterwards using `Files.newInputStream(outfile)` (well, that is, if `retcode` is 0; if it isn't, your command has ended with an error; which also means that you should redirect stderr somewhere, too)

Comment: Note: `redirectOutput()` is only available since Java 7.

Comment: @AaronDigulla yes, but then so is `Path`. And this is 2015, right? :p

Comment: final int retcode = pb.build().waitFor(); ---> am getting error in this line. I tried this too but same result

Comment: @PrasathBala yes, error from my part, I fixed it. It should have been .start(), not .build().

Comment: pb.redirectOutput(output.toFile()); ---> error near output.tofile

Comment: @fge - i changed the above line to pb.redirectOutput(outfile.toFile()); but the result throws error like "Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: And what file? The svn command or the output file? Does the parent directory exist?

Answer (score 0):

I/O redirection doesn't work well with `ProcessBuilder`. You should either call `cmd.exe` with

```
new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "svn ... > output.txt");
```

(i.e. you have to call `cmd` with exactly two arguments)
or you must redirect yourself, that is you need to start a background thread which reads stdout from the process and writes it to `output.txt`. In that case, you should use:

```
new ProcessBuilder("svn", "list", ...);
```

The former is brittle when you have spaces in arguments. So I suggest the latter even though the Java code is much more complex.

You should also have a look at [Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/) which makes it much easier to deal with external processes.

Or with Java 7, you can use `pb.redirectOutput();`

Comment: "you need to start a background thread which reads stdout from the process and writes it to output.txt" <-- eh? `ProcessBuilder` has `.redirectOutput()`...

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
String command = "svn list http://192.168.0.19/svn/cc/Branch/Jobs/tt/jobs/ --username prasadh --password prasadh2k";
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command.split());
processBuilder.redirectOutput(new File("C:/Users/dev112/output/", "output.txt"));
processBuilder.start();
```

Comment: Error: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "": CreateProcess error=87, The parameter is incorrect
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047) at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
 at org.archiveindexer.dao.RuntimeDemo.main(RuntimeDemo.java:33)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=87, The parameter is incorrect
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:385)
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:136)
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
 ... 1 more