# Executing several perl scripts at different times in one java program

Tags: java, multithreading, process, processbuilder

If my java program wants to execute several perl scripts at various times using threads. Should each thread have its own copy of a `ProcessBuilder` and `Process` objects ?

I was thinking that the threads could all share the ProcessBuilder but, i'm not too sure about that.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298717/can-a-thread-in-java-monitor-processes-that-it-starts

Answer (score 2):

- **If all the parameters of your `ProcessBuilder` are always the same** (i.e. you always call the same script with the same arguments), you can use the same `ProcessBuilder` in all your threads and only need to make sure that it is properly published to those threads.

  Typically, if you start your threads *after* having created and setup the `ProcessBuilder` you will be fine.
- **If however different threads need to make changes to the `ProcessBuilder`** (or if you make changes to the builder *after* the threads have been started), you will need to synchronize those changes - cf [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html):

  > **Note that this class is not synchronized**. If multiple threads access a `ProcessBuilder` instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies one of the attributes structurally, it *must* be synchronized externally.

  In that case, it would probably be easier to use one instance per thread.

Comment: yea these threads are calling different scripts so looks like i'll be going with one instance per thread.

Comment: @rage it will probably make your life easier.