# Using psql in linux with java to import a sql file

Tags: java, terminal, psql

I am using this method to send commands to the linux terminal

```
public static String execute(String command) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String[] commands = new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", command};
    try {
        Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(commands).start();
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

        String s = null;
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(s);
            sb.append("\n");
        }

        while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(s);
            sb.append("\n");
        } 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

It works fine with many commands like "ls", "date" etc..

but I wanna use a psql command to import a sql file to postgre like:

**psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d test -f test.sql**

I typed this command by hand in terminal and it works fine but not with the method above (the method works well with date,ls...)

It looks like the method entries in a kind of infinite loop when it calls psql. The method does not end when the method calls the psql.

ps: I used **export PGPASSWORD=pass** to avoid pass the password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem creating a file file.sh with

**export PGPASSWORD=pass**

**psql -h ip -p port -U user -d databaseName -f sqlFilePath**

**unset PGPASSWORD**

then I Use the method execute:

```
execute("chmod +x file.sh"); //to give permission to file execute

execute ("./file.sh") //to execute the file in terminal
```

in the end I delete the file.sh with

```
File file = new File("file.sh"); 
file.delete();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem here might be that you are trying to consume the input and error streams sequentially, when you must actually do them simultaneously. Consequently your first `readLine` call is blocking, waiting for the `readLine` to finish on the other stream.

You can solve this by using multiple threads to read the streams, or by redirecting stderr, or by just ditching all the output. Have a look at these threads:

- [ProcessBuilder: Forwarding stdout and stderr of started processes without blocking the main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165517/processbuilder-forwarding-stdout-and-stderr-of-started-processes-without-blocki)
- [Java ProcessBuilder: Resultant Process Hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285408/java-processbuilder-resultant-process-hangs)