# Correct place to read and write from stdin/stderr/stdout of external process which should be terminated within timeout

Tags: java, stream, stdout, stdin, processbuilder

I have the java application which starts external process through process builder.

External application interracts with rest "world" through `stdin`,`stdout`,`stderr`. Also this process should not be executed longer than some timeout.

code looks like this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(parameters);
Process process = pb.start();
OutputStream processOutputStream = process.getOutputStream();
IOUtils.write(inputJson, processOutputStream); // write data to external process
processOutputStream.close(); we don't need pass more arguments

InputStream errorStream = process.getErrorStream();

boolean responseWithinTimeout = process.waitFor(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); //app should work not longer than 2 sec
if (process.isAlive()) {
    process.destroyForcibly();
}
String stringFromErrorStream = IOUtils.toString(errorStream, "UTF-8"); //read from external application error stream
```

My questions:

1. Does 2000 niliseconds starts since`pb.start()` or since  `process.waitFor`
2. Is it correct to read from  `errorStream` when application already killed or it should be placed before `process.destroyForcibly()`?

Comment: It should be noticed that the process started won't end if either of STDIN or STDERR is not empty. This must have been mentioned somewhere on SO.

Comment: @glee8e What do you want to say? My application stop normally

Comment: In most times the process should be forcibly killed because of that holy timeout, not gracefully ended. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3285479/5818889

Answer (score 0):

> Does 2000 milliseconds starts `sincepb.start()`

No.

> or since `process.waitFor()`

Yes.

> Is it correct to read from `errorStream` when application already killed

No.

> or it should be placed before `process.destroyForcibly()`?

Yes. Best in a separate thread. You should also consume the process's `stdout`. Otherwise it can block.

Comment: Can you argue last comment?(why stream should be read before process destroy and why stdout should be consumed (I don't understand why it can be blocked))