# Unable to run maven task involving ProcessBuilder from intelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to debug a maven task from IntelliJ. which involves executing system command to start a service using ProcessBuilder.

e.g. I want to install package to my android device

`installApk(String package){
     ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder("adb install",package);
     Util.execute(pb); //Utility method to execute ProcessBuilder commands
 }`

It starts executing but gets stuck at point of execution of system command.

system command is not getting executed from IntelliJ (both Run and Debug mode).
But it works fine when I run the same task from terminal.

`mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.my.Main"`

I tried running it directly as main class and as well as mvn task configuration unsing intelliJ

I tried configuring IntelliJ to use my system's maven, instead of packaged one. It also didn't worked

Comment: No code = no answer.

Comment: External task execution can be blocked by several security tools. Do you happen to run AppSense, Avecto Privilege Guard or McAffee on this system? What OS do you use?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I am using Ubuntu Gnome

Comment: You may want to share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want to get help.

Comment: @CrazyCoder. added some sample code

Comment: How does it help to someone who wants to reproduce this problem?

Comment: @CrazyCoder, Try running it from IntelliJ as maven project instead of terminal, It is working fine from terminal

Comment: Why do you think the issue has any relation to Maven if running the main class from IntelliJ IDEA also hangs for you?

Comment: I think, it is some issue to user permission to execute system command using intellij.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285408/java-processbuilder-resultant-process-hangs