# How to run ffmpeg command in background from java

Tags: java

I am running a ffmpeg command from java Runtime.getRuntime().exec.
ffmpeg command basically cut the images from live stream.
Actually when i run this command without & then it works fine for five minutes after that it stops cutting images.

but when i use "&" in ffmpeg command it does not work at all.

there is no problem in live stream as when i ran this ffmpeg command from linux its working fine.

My main question is how to run a ffmpeg command in background from java.

Comment: ffmpeg command is working fine as tested in php

Answer (score 3):

The '&' is a *shell* directive to drop the task into the background. Running from `Process.exec()` doesn't involve the shell.

If your process is stalling (i.e. running but just not working) then I suspect that it's blocked waiting for you to consume stdout/stderr. You have to do this using threads to prevent the process blocking waiting for you to consume its output. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882772/capturing-stdout-when-calling-runtime-exec/882795#882795) for more details.

To run it in the background (i.e. whilst your Java process does other stuff) you need to:

1. spawn a new thread
2. invoke the process via `Process.exec` in this thread
3. consume stdout/stderr (both in separate threads) and finally get the exit code

Comment: I have tested with thread also..but still same result.
how to drop the task into the background means how to use "&"

Answer (score 1):

```
String livestream = "/Users/videos/video_10/video_1.mp4";

String folderpth = "/Users/videos/video_10/photos";

String cmd="/opt/local/bin/ffmpeg -i "+ livestream +" -r 10 "+folderpth+"/image%d.jpeg"; 

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

The video was 10 sec. long and it created 100 jpeg's in photos folder. You have to provide the absolute path of the folder.

Also to find the path for ffmpeg binary use `which ffmpeg` in terminal. Mine was `/opt/local/bin/ffmpeg`.

Answer (score 1):

I know you ask for help for **your command line problem in Java** but you might be interest in an other solution.

Maybe you can give a try to this library:
http://code.google.com/p/jjmpeg/

It's a wrapper for ffmpeg. 
Maybe you can try to create a java thread and run your command.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote it stops working after minutes. Did you check the exit code (`Process.exitValue()`). Also, did you check output stream and error stream from the external process?

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing the arguments in an array? If it works for a while are you giving it all the expected arguments? (print it out and check). Here is an example of my ffmpeg that I dug out for you.

```
String[] ffmpeg = new String[] {"ffmpeg", "-ss", Integer.toString(seconds),"-i", in, "-f", "image2", "-vframes", "1", out};
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(ffmpeg);
```

Comment: /usr/sites/ffmpeg -i livestream -r4 folderpth/image%d.jpeg

Comment: Did you try passing the arguments as a list of strings? Post some code in your original question to show us what you have. My code above takes  an integer argument for time an input file and outputs images.

Comment: here is the sample code..

String cmd="/usr/sites/ffmpeg -i"+ livestream +" -r4 "+folderpth+"/image%d.jpeg";
try{
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
}catch{}

Comment: Try it with a string array of parameters, not just a large string. I had some problems also using just a string and not a string array.

Comment: what is "in" and "out" param in your string array

Comment: they are strings which are file names, so test2.png is an example of out.