# get the data from batch file to java program

Tags: java, batch-file

i want to read the data from the batch file to java program. my java program is calling the batch file & it is giving the output for following command

C:>FIND "check" d:\c.txt

---------- D:\C.TXT
check

i want to read this "check" in my java program.

Thanks,
Murali

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown us how do you execute this batch. If you use `Runtime.exec()` then have a look at this example of capturing output: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the output of the `FIND` command to a dynamically named file and have it read by Java.

```
C:\FIND "check" d:\c.txt > yourUniqueFileName.txt
```

Then read the file `yourUniqueFileName.text`, parse and delete on the end (or not).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) or [Process](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) to `exec()` and then capture the output. More info [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html). You could redirect to a file and then read the file - however you're at the mercy of diskspace/permissioning issues, plus you should uniquely name your file etc.

Note that you'll need to be careful when capturing output from a spawned process. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882772/capturing-stdout-when-calling-runtime-exec/882795#882795) for more details.