# Log4j hanging my application

Tags: java, multithreading, log4j

Im trying to get console output from an external application in my application. When i call the externall app from my code it hangs with the message:

Configuring logging...

Configuring log4j from: C:\GPAT\log4j.cfg

and nothing happens. I searched through internet and it seems that it might be thread issue. But i cant modify this external application and i must go through log4j. I read the external app like this:

`StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();`

```
    try {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = rt.exec(GSATCommand);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println("Test running...");
        String line = null;
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);   // Writes the test output to console
            output.append(line);  output.append("\n");
        }
        int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
        System.out.println("Test successfully executed");
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consume both stdout and stderr from a spawned process in *separate* threads, to prevent blocking behaviour (your spawned process will write to buffers, and block if those buffers aren't being emptied by your consuming process).

See the 2nd paragraph of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882772/capturing-stdout-when-calling-runtime-exec/882795#882795) for more details and a link to a suitable fix.