# Process hangs in waitFor()

Tags: java, mysql, process

I am trying to run mysql to execute some files from java.
The input is read from a file and should be piped into the mysql process, everthing seems ok but the line

```
int exitCode = proc.waitFor();
```

never returns.

```
private boolean runScript(String path, String cmd, File file) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = rt.exec( path + File.separatorChar + cmd );
        OutputStream procOS = proc.getOutputStream();
        InputStream procES = proc.getErrorStream();
        InputStream procIS = proc.getInputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter procStdIn = new OutputStreamWriter( procOS );

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( file );
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( fis ) );
        String send;

        while ( ( send = reader.readLine() ) != null ) {
            procStdIn.write( send );
            System.out.println( send );
            copyStream( procES, System.err );
            copyStream( procIS, System.out );
        }
        procStdIn.write( "\r\nexit\r\n" );
        int exitCode = proc.waitFor();
        return exitCode == 0;
    }

    private void copyStream(InputStream is, PrintStream err) throws IOException {
        byte b[] = new byte[ 1024 ];
        int length;
        while ( is.available() > 0 && ( length = is.read( b ) ) > 0 ) {
            err.write( b, 0, length );
        }
```

}

Comment: Do you see that the child process has exited? Perhaps the `copyStream` needs to be done one last time after writing `exit` to it?

Comment: @Hemal No the cild process is still running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you're blocking reading stdout and stderr. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882772/capturing-stdout-when-calling-runtime-exec/882795#882795) for more details.

Comment: sorry the copyStream method does not block due to the call of avaliable().

Comment: Thanks the problem was the missing flush() on mysqls input stream.

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
procStdIn.flush();
```

after:

```
procStdIn.write( "\r\nexit\r\n" );
```