# how to capture wget command output inside groovy

Tags: groovy, cmd, wget, outputstream

I am execution a **wget** command inside my groovy code, the command is like this:

```
cmd /c C:/wget.exe -q -O - <my-URL>
```

When i actually run this command from **cmd** or windows run util, it works fine. But when i try to run this from within my groovy code, I don't see the output. 
How can i capture the output of this within groovy.

Thanks!

Comment: maybe a dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882772/capturing-stdout-when-calling-runtime-exec

Comment: groovy has a specific way of grabbing that content that is the more general java version

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
"cmd /c C:/wget.exe -q -O - <my-URL>".execute().text
```

But `new URL("<my-URL").text` might be a better way to load an url without relying on wget.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using wget why not just use groovy to get you the content:

```
def data = new URL(myUrl).getText()
```

Comment: But im getting below error while running above command for HTTPS URL - 

20:01:55  at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:99)
20:01:55  at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:432)
20:01:55 Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
20:01:55  at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
20:01:55  at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
20:01:55  at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.j