# BufferedReader and process.getOutputStream()

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm simply trying to execute a process in Java, so

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
this.process = null;

try {
    this.process = runtime.exec(new String[] {
        properties.getPropertyStr("ffmpegExecutable", "/usr/bin/ffmpeg"),
        "-i", this.streamEntry.getSource(),
        "-vcodec", "copy",
        "-acodec", "copy",
        this.streamEntry.getDestination()
    });
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}

BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader(???process.getOutputStream());
```

I simply want to be able to read the output of the process line by line. How do I do this?

Comment: Did you see this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882772/capturing-stdout-when-calling-runtime-exec

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
BufferedReader is;  // reader for output of process
String line;

// getInputStream gives an Input stream connected to
// the process standard output. Just use it to make
// a BufferedReader to readLine() what the program writes out.
is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

while ((line = is.readLine()) != null)
  System.out.println(line);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
BufferedReader in
   = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
```