# Reading the content of outpustream

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I have the following code in java that calls the date command in the command prompt:

```
// prepare command prompt runtime and process
Runtime runtime = null;
Process process = null;

// prepare output stream
OutputStream outputStream = null;

try {
   runtime = Runtime.getRuntime(); // instantiate runtime object
   process = runtime.exec("date"); // get the current date in command prompt

   // read the output of executing date command
   outputStream = process.getOutputStream();

   // output the date response
   System.out.println(outputStream);

   process.waitFor(); // wait for the date command to finish
} catch(Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} // end catch
```

How can I read the outputStream value for me to be able to use the System.output.println()

Comment: Is using the command line `date` program just a test or do you really think you need to get the date this way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capturing stdout when calling Runtime.exec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882772/capturing-stdout-when-calling-runtime-exec)

Comment: It's not actually the date command but the sqlldr (Oracle SQL*Loader) command that I'm executing here... I just put date to simplify my question.

Comment: Amazingly enough you can read an OutputStream with the `read()` method. ;)  However reading lines with a BufferedReader may be more useful in some cases. e.g. if there is more than one line.

Answer (score 2):

You don't read the output stream, you write to it to pass data to process. To read the data from process use

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
br.readLine();
```

The code is for string output of process. Of course if your process outputs data in other way you have to change the wrappers around `process.getInputStream()`

Update: I think it is in some way confusing that we use `getInputStream` to actually read process **output** :) The reason is that initially basic classes `OutputStream` and `InputStream` were named so relatively to the code that uses them (the code you write). So when you use `OutputStream` you actually use it as output for **your** program. When you use `process.getOutputStream` you don't get process' output but instead get your program output which is piped to process input. When you use `process.getInputStream` you get input for your program which obtains data piped from process' output.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this way without using OutputStream object

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("date");  
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));  
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();  
String line;  
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {  
  sb.append(line).append("\n");  
}  
String answer = sb.toString(); 
System.out.println(answer);
```