# Runtime.exec() doesn't work correct on tomcat / web application

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat

I have strange problem with run .exe program in my WebApplication. It works fine in console mode.

My exe application code:

```
            ...
            Console.WriteLine("before getEnvirement");
            IDictionary environmentVariables = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables();
            foreach (DictionaryEntry de in environmentVariables)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  {0} = {1}", de.Key, de.Value);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("before new Application");
            this.application = new App();
            Console.WriteLine("after new Application");
            ...
```

Where App() is class from COM library (I added reference of course).

My Java console / WebApplication code:

```
    try {
        String[] callAndArgs = {"C:\\temp\\program.exe", "arg1", "arg2"};
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(callAndArgs);
        p.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException Error: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Output in "console mode" (correct):

```
before getEnvirement
  <all my envirements>
before new Application
after new Application
```

Output in "web application mode" (bad):

```
before getEnvirement
  Path = C:\Windows\system32; <...>
  TEMP = C:\Windows\TEMP
```

or when I delete getEnvirement code (also bad):

```
before getEnvirement
before new Application
```

Exe application won't close itself on tomcat (I must use task manager to kill it)

And my questions: Why it dosn't work correct on tomcat? Why exe program have problems with getting system envirements when I run it on tomcat? And finally: why it works in console mode? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if your spawned process is blocking trying to write its output. From the doc for [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html):

> The created subprocess does not have its own terminal or console. All
>   its standard io (i.e. stdin, stdout, stderr) operations will be
>   redirected to the parent process through three streams
>   (getOutputStream(), getInputStream(), getErrorStream()). The parent
>   process uses these streams to feed input to and get output from the
>   subprocess. Because some native platforms only provide limited buffer
>   size for standard input and output streams, failure to promptly write
>   the input stream or read the output stream of the subprocess may cause
>   the subprocess to block, and even deadlock

You should be consuming the process' standard out/err as the process runs, and ideally in separate threads in order to avoid blocking. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/882795/12960) for more info.