# Executing external program in Java

Tags: java, process, runtime

I am trying to run "cut" inside a java program, but I am lost in terms of how to split the array of commands.
My program in the command line is the following:

```
cut file.txt -d' ' -f1-2  > hits.txt
```

And I am trying to run it inside java like this

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec(new String[]{"file.txt"," -d' ' -f1-2 "," > hits.txt"});
pr.waitFor();
```

But I get the following runtime error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cut file.txt": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

I attribute this error to the array of Strings I am using as exec commands. Any ideas on how to do this? Also any known documentation on the issue. Thanks

Comment: `pr2` and `rt2`? Please fix your variable names.

Comment: It looks like either the user that runs the java process does not have permission to the file `file.txt`, or, more likely, file.txt is not in the same directory from where you are running the java process. You may correct the relative path or switch to an absolute path.

Comment: Is this the exact code?  Shouldn't cut be in the command array?

Comment: @MattHarrison this is exactly what I was asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make either an script for bash:

```
"/bin/bash" "-c" "cut file.txt -d' ' -f1-2  > hits.txt"
```

or split

```
"cut" "file.txt" "-d" "' '" "-f" "1-2"
```

The error message clearly says:

```
Cannot run program "cut file.txt"
```

so it interprets "cut file.txt" as a single programname with a blank inside.

Your problem starts with the redirection, because you can't redirect the output that way:

```
"cut" "file.txt" "-d" "' '" "-f" "1-2" ">" "hits.txt"
```

You have to handle input and output streams. It might be a better idea to implement `cut` in Java, to get a portable solution, or call a script which the user may specify on commandline or in a config file, so that it can be adapted for Windows or other platforms.

Calling /bin/bash and redirecting there should work - on unix like systems.

Comment: @JulioDiaz: `-c` means, here follows a command. see `bash --help`. The command is the third String, which gets parsed as a whole script by bash.

Answer (score 1):

If you want output redirection, you have to do it yourself. `> hits.txt` will not do what you want. Redirecting stdout from a process called by `exec` is covered [in another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882772/capturing-stdout-when-calling-runtime-exec).

The error you're showing isn't consistent with the source code you've listed here- there's no source for `cut`, for one thing. It's definitely trying to understand `cut file.txt` to be the complete relative path to a single executable with a space in its name, which is almost certainly not what you want. It would be easier to troubleshoot this with correct code.