# Java runtime exec

Tags: java, command, runtime, system, exec

I am trying to do something using system exec in Java

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Surprisingly everything that is related with paths, directories and files is not working well

I don't get why and just want to know is there any **alternatives**?

Comment: tell us what you are trying to do. then only we can give proper help

Comment: *"`Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);` Surprisingly.."* Not to me.  See [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  Also, for better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Why not use J2SE classes and methods for accessing the file-system?

Comment: `cd` is not going to work. That is not an executable, that is a function of your shell.

Comment: @Thilo Thanks! what is the alternative of cd

Comment: Without knowing what the `command` value is, we can only guess.

Answer (score 4):

The alternative is to use the [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class, which has a somewhat cleaner interface, but your main problem is probably related to how the OS processes command lines, and there isn't much Java can do to help you with that.

Answer (score 2):

As noted above, cd is a shell builtin. i.e. it's not an executable. You can determine this using:

```
$ which cd
cd: shell built-in command
```

As it's not a standalone executable, `Runtime.exec()` won't be able to do anything with it.

You may be better off writing a shell script to do the shell-specific stuff (e.g. change the working directory) and then simply execute that shell script using `Runtime.exec()`. You can set PATH variables etc. within your script and leave Java to simply execute your script.

One thing that catches people out is that you have to consume your script's stdout/stderr (even if you throw it away). If you don't do this properly your process will likely block. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/882795/12960) for more details.

Comment: well, thanks. I'll try to figure it out. shell script isn't a good idea I need streams

Comment: Can you elaborate re. your streams comment ?

Answer (score 0):

The exec() method can take three arguments.  The third is the directory your subprocess should use as its working directory.  That solves your "cd" problem, anyway.