# How do I display terminal window output in TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-ndk

I am using my Android app to launch a native binary.  I would like to display the output of that binary in a small window in my application.  How would I go about either displaying the output in a TextView or showing the terminal in a small window (preferred)?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What exactly is the problem - you're not sure how to capture the output into a variable, or you're not sure how to display said variable in a window? Note that calls for ready to use, complete solutions normally go unheeded here at SO. For that, Rent-A-Coder exists.

Comment: I'm not looking for a full code solution, I'm looking for a suggested path or an Android SDK package/method that allows you to display the command line execution of my binary.

Comment: It's not a single method, it's a fairly involved piece. The cleanest way of doing this would probably involve dropping to the NDK level. Without that, you can probably use an intermediate file and shell-level input redirection. I'll sketch out the latter for you.

Comment: How is _"showing the terminal in a small window"_ different from a small TextView?

Answer (score 1):

The gist of the article that Alex linked to is that `Runtime.exec()` returns a `Process` object, which lets you get the process' standard output (and `stderr`, too) as Java streams via `Process.getOutputStream()/getErrorStream()`. Get them, read them in a thread (they do properly block - you don't want to block the UI thread), pass the data back to the UI thread. Much, much better. I rescind my previous answer.

The article also recommends wrapping the stream in a `BufferedReader` so that you can do `readLine`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one scheme. NDK is not necessary for this one.

You create a temporary file in your app's data dir. You run the binary, specifying the same file as an output direction in the command line using `Runtime.exec()`. The command line you'll have to specify would invoke not the binary itself, but `sh`, and one of the command line parameters would be a redirection: `>myfile.txt`.

You then start a worker thread that reads the same file. You'll need to carefully implement new data detection - as this is a file, not a pipe, the reading operation will simply terminate once the end of file is reached; it won't block until new data appears.

Then you pass the data from the worker thread using `Activity.runOnUiThread()` or `Handler.post()` to the main thread, where it's used to update TextView's content.

A cleaner way would involve creating a pipe pair with `mkfifo()` and redirecting output in place using `dup2()` from a pipe handle to the file handle value 1 (`stdout`). That's how they normally do it in the C/Linux world. There's probably an Android example out there, I've never done that.

Oh, and before you do all that, make sure the binary does not have a more palatable interface. More often than not, Linux binaries are based on a static/dynamic library where all the yummy functionality is, one that can be linked with and called directly.

EDIT: Especially if it's `logcat`. There are other ways to read a log in Android.

Comment: Thanks, I like the suggestion of using a file as an interface to both levels.  In this case libpcap and libpthread are being utilized, but there is a lot of other functionality that I need in the binary that doesn't exist in a library.

Comment: If the answer solves your problem, please accept it. I still think that the `mkfifo()/dup2()` avenue is worth pursuing, but the code will get considerably hairier. Up to you.

Comment: You don't need temporary files, and don't have to worry about pipes, and have no reason to dig into NDK. Java provides a clean and rich mechanism for capturing output from child processes, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882772/capturing-stdout-when-calling-runtime-exec

Comment: @Alex Cohn: why don't you write an answer of your own, rather than comment on mine? SO was kind of meant for this sort of thing...

Comment: I did not post an answer, first of all, because I did not understand the question, re: terminal vs. TextView. Also, it would require lots of typing, and I was far from my keyboard (and still am). But I thought that the correction was necessary, and even urgent, and I think you did a great job adding a separate answer about it.