# how to pass the arguments to the shell command through java?

Tags: java, shell, unix, exec

I am new to this kind of integration of java with Unix.

what i am trying to do is

```
    String command="passwd";
    Runtime rt=Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        Process pc=rt.exec(command);
        try {
            pc.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pc.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";

        while ((line=buf.readLine())!=null) {

        System.out.println(line);

        }
        BufferedReader buf1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pc.getErrorStream()));

        String line1 = "";
        while ((line1=buf1.readLine())!=null) {

            System.out.println("Error--"+line1);

            }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("IOException---"+e1.getMessage());
    }
```

now when i am trying to pass the "passwd" command the Unix environment goes to suspended mode.

I want to know how can i pass the old password ,new password and confirm new password to the shell using the java code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass it in using the confusing named [Process.getOutputStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream%28%29). From the doc:

> Gets the output stream of the subprocess. Output to the stream is
>   piped into the standard input stream of the process represented by
>   this Process object

Note that you need to capture the processes stdout/err *simultaneously* to avoid blocking. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/882795/12960) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

There is a utility called **expect**. If u installed u can pass argument for any thing. So construct as string execute by
String ConstructedCommand;
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(ConstructedCommand);

This link will be deserve your need. http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect