# Calling exe using Runtime.getrunTime hangs when wait method is used

Tags: java, web-services, process, runtime.exec

I am using the `Runtime.getRunTime()` method to call an exe for web service in Java. If I call this without using `Process.wait()` then it works fine but if I use this with the `wait()` method then my process hangs and I have to restart Tomcat.

Can any one tell why this happens?

Comment: A code snippet showing what you have, what's working, and what's not, would help.

Answer (score 0):

[This shows you WHY](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) the program "waitsFor()" the external process to finish executing.

Now, there is a possibility that the external program is requesting stdout and stderr, which your program is blocking. This is causing a perpetual wait or what's called the deadlock. [See this for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882772/capturing-stdout-when-calling-runtime-exec/882795#882795).

Comment: If I use waitFor() then process waits indefinite time and I have to restart tomcat server .My code snippet for this is: Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("--path of exe which I taken from cmd line parameter") p.waitFor()

Comment: @matti that's probably because your program is going into a deadlock. One is waiting for the other process to exit, while the other process is waiting to gain "stdout"/"stderr" access.