# Running non-existing jar does not cause any expection/error

Tags: java, exception, process, jar, runtime.exec

Please, consider the following snippet which is being run from Eclipse.

Even though the external jar file does not exist no Exception is thrown and `process` is not null. **Why is it so?**

```
try {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar NonExisting.jar");

    if (process == null)
            System.out.println("process = null");
    else
        System.out.println(process);
     } catch (IOException e) {
         System.err.println(e);
}
```

It prints

```
java.lang.ProcessImpl@1a4d139
```

If I run it manully from command line then there is an error:

```
C:\Users\workspace\Project\src>java -jar NonExisting.jar
Error: Unable to access jarfile NonExisting.jar
```

Comment: Because the java process is running/executed. You'll get an error if you try to run a non existing executable. You have to check the java.exe **exit code**.

Comment: As a general tip, follow the link to the JavaWorld article linked from the [exec info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/runtime.exec/info) & follow **all** the recommendations.  If that code had done so, the outcome would have been more clear.  Also, unless you intend to support 1.4, use `ProcessBuilder` to create the `Process` & separate the `String` arguments into a `String[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Process.waitFor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) gives you the exit code of the spawned process, and is likely returning a non-zero (i.e. error) value. You should check this value, and collect the `stdout`/`err` at the same time (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882772/capturing-stdout-when-calling-runtime-exec) for more info). `stderr` will likely report an error.

All you're currently doing is confirming that the process has been invoked. The process then tries/fails to load the jar file, and that's when it exists and reports an error.

Comment: Why `waitFor` and `exitValue` declared as abstract? Can I really call it?

Comment: You can. The Process class returned is abstract and you'll be given a derived implementation, which provides these methods.

Comment: Is that implementation native to OS? How can get more information about  the returned object rather than that it extends Process?

Answer (score 1):

The process was created and finished. You should check the return value of the `Process` object. An exception will be thrown if there is a problem with the creation of the new process, so here you don't get an exception.

Comment: Yes, `exitValue()` returns 1 if the jar does not exist. But now I test with existing jar and `exitValue()` throws `java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: process has not exited`

Answer (score 1):

Whoa, this is quite ugly :-) Why dont you start the Main Methd of the jar in a new thread? Well you should check the exit status of the process:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.htm

You are basically forking the process so you cannot get exceptions or anything java specific from this, you need to deal with the new process, like any other OS specific app.