# command works in Windows cmd but fails with Runtime.getRuntime.exec()

Tags: java, windows

Windows 7 `cmd` has no trouble executing `ping -n 5 127.0.0.1 > nul`.  Also, `Runtime.getRuntime.exec(new String[]{"ping", "-n", "5", "127.0.0.1"})` works fine.

But `Runtime.getRuntime.exec(new String[]{"ping", "-n", "5", "127.0.0.1", ">",
"nul"})` fails with `Bad parameter >`. Why?

I'm using Java7 in Java6 mode.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882772/capturing-stdout-when-calling-runtime-exec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `>` redirection is not part of the ping command, it is part of `cmd` itself.  When `exec()` sees the `>` it tries to feed it to `ping` as an argument.

To get the same functionality, just read (and ignore) data from the `InputStream` from the `Process` `exec` return value.

Answer (score 1):

Because `>` is not a valid argument for `ping`. When executed on the command prompt the `>` is interpreted as output direction, but when used from `Runtime().exec()` it is not interpreted and is passed to `ping` as an argument (hence the error message).

To capture the output (unintuitively) use [`Process.getInputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream%28%29) (an instance of `Process` is returned by `Runtime.exec()`).

Comment: Close.  The output of the `Process` is in `getInputStream()`  I know that sounds backwards.

Comment: @MelNicholson, thank you. Just reread the documentation. Confusing indeed.