# .jar not executing and showing the System.out.print(); output

Tags: java, runtime.exec

My problem is when to call jar file using

> Runtime.getRuntime().exec() method, my .jar is not executing and showing its output

Coding is like that

> public static void main(String[] args) {
>
> ```
>   String execJar = "java -jar C:\test.jar";       
>
>   try {
>
>       Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(execJar);
>
>   } catch (IOException e) {
>         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }       
> }
> ```

When I used this "java -jar C:\test.jar" in command prompt, my .jar is not executing thus not showing System.out output.
Does anybody know how I can make this work?

Thanks.

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream()

Comment: Yet another fragile implementation of creating a `Process`!  Do yourself a favor and go through the Java World article linked from the [`exec` info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/runtime.exec/info).  It might not solve the problem, but at least you will have more information.  After that, split the arguments into a `String[]` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the `Process`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson if your comment was an answer, I'd +1 it.

Comment: @Fildor  I'm afraid it does not quite qualify as an answer (unfortunately).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-Xmx1024m", "-Xms1024m",
         "-DTOOLS_DIR=C://", "-Daoi=whole", 
         "-jar", "C://calc.jar");
try {
    pb.start();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.print("EEE"+ex);
}
```

This is easy to follow as it has simple paths so you can try it and let it run easily

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a process from within Java, it will have it's own standard out and standard error streams in that particular process. To access those, you have to get the corresponding streams from the `Process` object you have created.

```
p.getOutputStream(); // System.out
p.getErrorStream();  // System.err
```

Comment: I want to show information of 'System.out' in jar file to console, when calling Runtime.getRuntime().exec() method.

Comment: Then just handle the streams accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Where do you expect the `System.out` to go ?.

When the process is spawned, the input/output and error streams are opened between the spawning and spawned process. You *should* consume the input and error (these represent the process *output*, despite the confusing name), otherwise your spawned process will block, waiting for the streams' contents to be consumed.

See [this answer for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/882795/12960).

Answer (score 0):

```
  ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-Xmx1024m", "-Xms1024m",
         "-DTOOLS_DIR=F://Net Beans Work Space//calc//dist", "-Daoi=whole", 
         "-jar", "F://Net Beans Work Space//calc//dist//calc.jar");

  pb.start();
```

Use this code it will surely run your jar file what you have to change is the paths in above code please reply it will work for you I will be thankful for you kind reply

Comment: "-DTOOLS_DIR=F://Net Beans Work Space//calc//dist" it means the dist folder of you containing the .jar file (change it for your path) "F://Net Beans Work Space//calc//dist//calc.jar" it means give it the whole complete path of your .jar file I'm waiting for your answer desperately please let me know if it was helpful

Comment: What does this have to do with where system.out ends up?

Comment: @Nilsh what are you talking about sorry not getting your point

Comment: The problem is to capture the output, not executing the command. Although it would be better using `ProcessBuilder`, that's not the OPs issue.

Comment: @Nilish For your kind information the user wants to create a process and execute a .jar ok!

Comment: If the question was to just exec the command, then I suggest the OP updates his question to reflect that, as it has nothing to do with where the output ends up. I know perfectly what execute does, thank you...