# process.waitFor() returns one on of my computers but not on my other computer

Tags: java

I have this code

```
private static void restartTor() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    String killTor = "killall tor";
    String startTor = "/opt/local/bin/tor -f /dev/torrc";
    Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process pr = run.exec(killTor);
    pr.waitFor();
    BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
    String line = "";
    while ((line=buf.readLine())!=null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    pr = run.exec(startTor);
    pr.waitFor();
    buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
    line = "";
    while ((line=buf.readLine())!=null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

When I run this on computer A it executes as expected but when I run it on my second computer, B, it gets stuck at the second `pr.waitFor();`.

I have read a bunch of questions here on SE, such as [process.waitFor() never returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483830/process-waitfor-never-returns) and [Java process.waitFor() does not return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546225/java-process-waitfor-does-not-return) and the main issue there seems to be that you don't read the buffer but I do that (don't I?).

A and B are similar, but not identical (Macs, running 10.15, A has 32 GB RAM, B has 16 GB RAM).

I use the same version of tor and the torrc:s are identical on A and B.

I am stumped. What is the problem here?

---

Edit: On B, If I manually, from a regular terminal, kill the process, it returns and everything continues as expected.

Edit 2: Now it fails on computer A as well. I had run it dozens of times there, without problems before but now it fails constantly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this this is the ultimate cause of your problem, but you should call `waitFor` **after** reading the output (and errors) from the external process.  If a process writes more to its standard output and error streams than the OS is prepared to buffer, then your code could deadlock:

- The external process is blocked while trying to write output
- Your Java code is blocked waiting for the external process to exit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consume both streams at same time if you are experiencing the stream deadlock issue on `waitFor()`. You can do this with background threads on `pr.getErrorStream()`, or set up STDERR handling before calling `waitFor()`.

To do this replace use of `Runtime.exec` with ProcessBuilder.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(startTor);
```

This is easier with either sending error log to a file:

```
File stderr = new File("stderr.log");
pb.redirectError(stderr));
```

... or just redirect error to merge it with stdout:

```
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
```

then

```
pr = pb.start();
pr.waitFor();
```