# Unable to run unix code from jsp webpage

Tags: linux, jsp, unix

Have a problem in running unix code in jsp page, my jsp code is as below.

```
<%@page language="java" %>

<%@page import="java.util.*" %>

<html>

<head>

<%
    String unixCommand = "/bin/bash -lc \"/home/chandu/test/./check.sh xxxxxx\"";

     Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

     rt.exec(unixCommand);
    System.out.println("Print Test Line.");

%>

</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Unix code is below

## !/bin/bash -l

cd /home/chandu/test/
for i in `cat nodelist`
do
java -cp /home/chandu/test jcmd "$i" ZMIO:MSISDN=$1: > "$i".log
done
vlradd=`grep MSC-ADDRESS *.log | awk '{print $4}'`
mss=`grep $vlradd mss | awk '{print $1}'`
java -cp /home/chandu/test jcmd "$mss" ZMVO:MSISDN=$1: | egrep "LOCATION AREA CODE OF IMSI|LAST USED CELL ID" | cut -d "/" -f2 > output
lac=`head -1 output | tail -1`
cellid=`head -2 output | tail -1`
echo $lac       $cellid
You have new mail in /var/mail/root

Comment: And your problem is what ?

Comment: Servlet Container right problem or @BrianAgnew answer...

Answer (score 0):

You need to

1. collect the standard out/err from the Unix process and write into your JSP.
2. use `Process.waitFor()` to wait for the process exist and collection the return code. Otherwise you'll have a [zombie process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process).

You need to read from the streams provided by the `Process` object returned by `rt.exec()` to capture the output. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/882795/12960) for more details.

Comment: @BrainAgnew I have kept my unix code also, couldnt figure out what exactly is the problem, there is no jsp error though.