# Redirect minecraft's print stream to a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, minecraft, printstream

I am making a Minecraft launcher, and i would like to make my own ftb-style console to go with it. any ideas on how i would redirect Minecraft's print stream to a `JTextArea`?

Comment: what's the problem: getting hold of the printstream or its output on a JTextArea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to create an implementation of `PrintStream` and replace `System.out` and `System.err` with it, by `System.setOut` and `System.setErr`, respectively. You might also want to replace `System.in` for input, depending on whether this is for the MineCraft client or server.

There are many articles on piping PrintStreams to Swing components. On such article describing the process can be found [here](http://unserializableone.blogspot.ca/2009/01/redirecting-systemout-and-systemerr-to.html). A search engine query resembling "redirecting PrintStream to JTextPane" will also bring up a handful of links.

Comment: i am already able to redirect the PrintStream, but for some reason when i start up minecraft's main class, it refuses to print

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this StreamGobbler example: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=4

The other answers on this other SO question may also help: [Capturing stdout when calling Runtime.exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882772/capturing-stdout-when-calling-runtime-exec)