# Executing a Linux command (mutt) on java shell not working properly

Tags: java, linux, shell

I have a situation where I want (need) do send a file by e-mail at the execution of a given java program. The copy commands are executed fine either on Windows and Linux, **however, mutt is not working when the execution is ordered on java**. The command string is generated flawless, (I currently manually type the string printed to console to manually send the e-mail), however the Runtime.getRuntime.exec() is not executing it properly.

```
        if (OS.indexOf("win") >= 0)
        {
            // windows
            cmd = "cmd /C copy "+workbookFileName+" "+latestWorkbookFileName;
            System.out.println("executing command windows: "+cmd);
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        }
        else
        {
   //         others
            cmd = "cp "+workbookFileName+" "+latestWorkbookFileName;
            System.out.println("executing Linux: "+cmd);
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);



            cmd = "echo \"This is the message body\" | mutt -a \""+workbookFileName+"\" -s \"message subject\" -- sqlinjection@domain.com";
            System.out.println("executing Linux: "+cmd);
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

            System.out.println("bye");


        }
```

Comment: Most likely you are getting an error and unless you read the output, you won't see it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good tutorial on how to use `Runtime.exec` [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).

The idea is that you need to consume the **standard input, output and error** for the process created by `Runtime.exec` and the site i mentioned is perfect.

Comment: I used the StreamGobbler, the process exits with value 0 (success), the standard input is consumed, but i don't get the e-mail on my inbox :(

Comment: try replacing `cmd = "echo \"This is the message body\" | mutt -a \""+workbookFileName+"\" -s \"message subject\" -- sqlinjection@domain.com";` with `cmd = "bash -ic 'echo \"This is the message body\" | mutt -a \""+workbookFileName+"\" -s \"message subject\" -- sqlinjection@domain.com' ";` basically run the whole command inside a shell. I had the same problem once.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. consume stdout/stderr from the spawned process. Note that you'll have to do this in separate threads in order to avoid blocking the process whilst it waits for you to read. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/882795/12960) for more details
2. use `Process.waitFor()` to collect the exit code of the spawned process

Unrelated: Check out [Files.copy()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html) to perform cross-platform file copy operations