# Run Oracle import Command from Java and see Console output

Tags: java, oracle, imp

I am running an Oracle database Command for a `.dmp` file like this:

```
String impcmd = "imp askul/askul@askdb file=mydumpfile.dmp log=mylogfile.log fromuser=askul touser=askul full=N ignore=Y grants=Y indexes=Y";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(impcmd);
p.waitFor();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line = br.readLine();
while(line != null){
System.out.println(line);
line = br.readLine();
}
```

The database import is Happening Fine on the Background, but I want to be Able to see the console output as the Import goes on as I now have to guess whether it is complete or not. What Am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture the stdout and stderr in separate threads (to prevent blocking) and output this as you get it, *whilst waiting for the process to complete*.

Note that you may need to read both stdout *and* stderr. Or your output may be going to the configured log file instead.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/882795/12960) for more info and references to example code. Also check [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html), which discusses common pitfalls when using `Runtime.exec()`

Comment: Man I cant get a thing out of that article.

Comment: What precisely is the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just want to move the call to `waitFor`.

```
// p.waitFor();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line = br.readLine();
while(line != null){
  System.out.println(line);
  line = br.readLine();
}
p.waitFor(); // <-- to here.
```

Comment: Still happenning in the BAckground even after I moved `p.waitFor();` to after the while loop.

Comment: Are you sure there's console output to get?

Comment: If I went to cmd and executed this command, it will show importing table...... 23rows.. Something like this. This is what I want to see.

Comment: could the output have gone to stderr?