# java code to export oracle 11g dump file to the database

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, runtime.exec

I have shell script for creating dump file of oracle 11g database. I want to run it through java code, I did find any working solutions on the web. Can anyone help me on this.

**Script**

```
expdp test/test@localhost:1521/ORCL DIRECTORY=orcl_full2 DUMPFILE=testDBUser.dmp LOGFILE=full_exp_TestDBUser.log FULL=YES
```

One solution I found mentioned below, but it did not work for me :

[Run Oracle import Command from Java and see Console output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21433706/run-oracle-import-command-from-java-and-see-console-output)

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) *"it did not work for me"* How did it fail? Be specific, we are not mind readers.   3) See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters.

Comment: Got it. I will keep it in my mind next time onwards.

Comment: Will look more closely at the question, next time onwards. Of course, if you choose to [edit] the ***current*** question as suggested & notify me when it is..

Comment: Actually, I got the solution. I problem was, I was trying to run this program on windows platform considering that it will connect to remote Linux server and execute it in there. But when I executed the same program on Linux environment. Guess what, It worked.

Comment: Now you might write an answer below, or simply delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution :** My problem was, I was trying to run this program on windows platform considering that it will connect to remote Linux server and execute it in there. But when I executed the same program on Linux environment.