# Hang of java application on Linux

Tags: java, linux, jvm

I run my application on linux, and sometimes it is hung.

please help me understand why it is hung. Please find callstack below. I supposed that something wrong with jvm.

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/jstack -F 14429
Attaching to process ID 14429, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 23.25-b01
Deadlock Detection:

No deadlocks found.

Thread 14430: (state = BLOCKED)


Thread 14698: (state = IN_NATIVE)
 - java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(byte[], int, int) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.io.FileInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) @bci=4, line=242 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill() @bci=175, line=235 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(byte[], int, int) @bci=44, line=275 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) @bci=49, line=334 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.io.FilterInputStream.read(byte[]) @bci=5, line=107 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.commons.exec.StreamPumper.run() @bci=31, line=105 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=724 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 14697: (state = IN_NATIVE)
 - java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(byte[], int, int) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.io.FileInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) @bci=4, line=242 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill() @bci=175, line=235 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(byte[], int, int) @bci=44, line=275 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) @bci=49, line=334 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.io.FilterInputStream.read(byte[]) @bci=5, line=107 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.commons.exec.StreamPumper.run() @bci=31, line=105 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=724 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 14695: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Object.wait() @bci=2, line=503 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.UNIXProcess.waitFor() @bci=8, line=210 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine, java.util.Map, java.io.File, org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteStreamHandler) @bci=106, line=347 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.access$200(org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor, org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine, java.util.Map, java.io.File, org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteStreamHandler) @bci=6, line=46 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor$1.run() @bci=29, line=188 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 14621: (state = IN_NATIVE)
 - java.lang.UNIXProcess.waitForProcessExit(int) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.UNIXProcess.access$200(java.lang.UNIXProcess, int) @bci=2, line=54 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.UNIXProcess$3.run() @bci=11, line=174 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=95, line=1145 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=615 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=724 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 14496: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Object.wait() @bci=2, line=503 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop() @bci=28, line=526 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.TimerThread.run() @bci=1, line=505 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 14464: (state = BLOCKED)


Thread 14454: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(long) @bci=44, line=135 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove() @bci=2, line=151 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run() @bci=16, line=189 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 14453: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Object.wait() @bci=2, line=503 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run() @bci=46, line=133 (Interpreted frame)
```

Comment: Your process appears to be blocked waiting for a unix process.  I would look at what your program is running. e.g. look for a child process.

Comment: Can you attach a debugger?

Comment: Thanks, my java app runs selenium 2 (WebDriver) with FirefoxDriver support. Seems firefox is unable to exit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Peter Lawrey says, it seems that you are blocked in a waitFor() call in your code.

Maybe you are reading from process STDOUTPUT but not from STDERROR... Take a look at this ancient SO post [Capturing stdout when calling Runtime.exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882772/capturing-stdout-when-calling-runtime-exec/882795#882795)

EDIT: If you are using a ProcessBuilder in your code, try

`yourProcessBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);`