# Spigot Thread Dump

Tags: java, multithreading, minecraft, thread-dump

When I shutdown my Minecraft server instance, the following thread dump is generated:

```
[00:02:53] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving chunks for level 'ServerLevel[Caelum]'/minecraft:caelum
[00:04:42] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]: ------------------------------
[00:04:42] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]: The server has stopped responding! This is (probably) not a Spigot bug.
[00:04:42] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]: If you see a plugin in the Server thread dump below, then please report it to that author
[00:04:42] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:       *Especially* if it looks like HTTP or MySQL operations are occurring
[00:04:42] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]: If you see a world save or edit, then it means you did far more than your server can handle at once
[00:04:42] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:       If this is the case, consider increasing timeout-time in spigot.yml but note that this will replace the crash with LARGE lag spikes
[00:04:42] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]: If you are unsure or still think this is a Spigot bug, please report to https://www.spigotmc.org/
[00:04:42] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]: Be sure to include ALL relevant console errors and Minecraft crash reports
[00:04:42] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]: Spigot version: git-Spigot-17d78db-f8d4da0 (MC: 1.16.3)
[00:04:42] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]: ------------------------------
[00:04:42] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]: Server thread dump (Look for plugins here before reporting to Spigot!):
[00:04:42] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]: ------------------------------
[00:04:42] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]: Current Thread: Server thread
[00:04:42] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:      PID: 30 | Suspended: false | Native: false | State: WAITING
[00:04:42] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:      Stack:
[00:04:42] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:              sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
[00:04:42] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:              java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
[00:04:42] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:              java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Signaller.block(CompletableFuture.java:1707)
[00:04:42] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:              java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3323)
[00:04:42] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:              java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.waitingGet(CompletableFuture.java:1742)
[00:04:42] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:              java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.join(CompletableFuture.java:1947)
[00:04:42] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:              net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.IChunkLoader.i(IChunkLoader.java:101)
[00:04:42] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:              net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.PlayerChunkMap.save(PlayerChunkMap.java:328)
[00:04:42] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:              net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.ChunkProviderServer.save(ChunkProviderServer.java:309)
[00:04:42] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:              net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.WorldServer.save(WorldServer.java:760)
[00:04:42] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:              net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.MinecraftServer.saveChunks(MinecraftServer.java:674)
[00:04:42] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:              net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.MinecraftServer.stop(MinecraftServer.java:741)
[00:04:42] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:              net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.DedicatedServer.stop(DedicatedServer.java:644)
[00:04:42] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:              net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:887)
[00:04:42] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:              net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.MinecraftServer.lambda$0(MinecraftServer.java:164)
[00:04:42] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:              net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.MinecraftServer$$Lambda$3216/303218042.run(Unknown Source)
[00:04:42] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:              java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Full Thread Dump:

https://pastebin.com/5Kzn9mcS

I have tried delaying shut down, removing any database connections, removing proxy hosts, everything. Nothing has worked. This crash ONLY happens when the server is shut down, and only happens on our remote CENT OS 7 host (does not happen on windows).

I user Hibernate as my ORM & handling database issues.

At this point, does someone see something in this thread dump that I don't? Does anyone see whats actually *causing* the unsafe park issue?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The main thread is waiting for something to exit.

Such as it takes too many times, it throw an error. You can see it because there is only this thread that is in `Runnable`, all others are waiting.

I suggest you to be sure that everything is closed.

Also, it's possible that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21496376/10952503) answer help you.