# Catch error messages from ksh script executed by getRuntime().exec using getErrorStream?

Tags: java, unix, ksh

I need to execute ksh script from java, where I want to exit with error and provide error message.

exit 1 - exits with error code 1

But what should I do in script in order to catch the error message with getErrorStream?

```
 proc =    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(SCRIPT_PATH);

 int exitV = proc.waitFor();
if(exitV !=0){
  InputStream iputStream= proc.getErrorStream();
  BufferedReader iput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iputStream));
  while ((line = iput.readLine()) != null){
   msg.append(line);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to consume both stdout and stderr *whilst the process is running*, rather than once its completed.

Note that you have to do this in separate threads, otherwise your process runs the risk of blocking. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/882795/12960) for more details.