# Catch stdout using java

Tags: java, stdout, execute

What is the best way, how to catch `stdout` using java?

Demonstration:

**PROGRAM A** start **PROGRAM B**, **PROGRAM B** print some output to console (using `System.println("...")`), how can i catch from **PROGRAM A** output in console from **PROGRAM B**?

**My way is:**

start Program B and redirect the output to a file ( `PROGRAM B > output.txt` )

Is there any better way?

I hope, you understand me :-)

EDIT:

I found on internet code, its work:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String program = "config_dir\\lib\\TestProject.jar";
    // Run a java app in a separate system process
    Process proc;
    try {
        proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar " + program + " a b c");
        // Then retreive the process output
        InputStream in = proc.getInputStream();
        InputStream err = proc.getErrorStream();
        System.out.println(convertStreamToString(in));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


}                                        
private String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
    java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
    return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
}
```

Comment: It depends. Do you want standard output on a file or do you want to inspect it in program A? - Either way, look a java.lang.ProcessBuilder for options to handle standard output without requiring shell redirection.

Comment: I want inspect it in program A.

Comment: Tell us what is wrong with the outcome of your code. If you see an exception, post that exception. If the program writes something else then expected, write both expected and actual output.

Comment: Also try `System.err.println(convertStreamToString(err));` sometimes error in starting program (`java` not in classpath, `.jar` file not found, etc) goes to the `stderr` of that newly creted process instead of causing exception in the original program.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capturing stdout when calling Runtime.exec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882772/capturing-stdout-when-calling-runtime-exec)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a minimum quantity of code to read the output of /bin/cat which copies a file to standard output:

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder( "/bin/cat", "some.file" );
    Process process = pb.start();
    InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    int c;
    while( (c = is.read()) != -1 ){
        System.out.print( (char)c + "-" );
    }
    process.waitFor();
```