# RUN and display cmd using -- java

Tags: java, cmd

I am executing multiple CMD line. I used `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c command line 1 & command line 2\"");` to execute. The problem what i am facing is, the execution for my query took more time, the string what i am getting out from CMD  take more time moreover the string will produce only after entire cmd got executed. Is it possible to get the line by line command execution. Let me know if i made any mistakes.

Comment: More time than what?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882772/capturing-stdout-when-calling-runtime-exec