# Redirect "System.out.print" output of a Java program to a txt file

Tags: java

Code for redirecting the print output within the program:

```
   try
   {
       System.out.println("Print on console");

       // Store console print stream.
       PrintStream ps_console = System.out;

       File file = new File("C:/Users/John/Desktop/compiletest/output" + trialNum + ".txt");
       FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
       PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);
       System.setOut(ps);
       System.out.println("Print in the file !!");

       // Set console print stream.
       //System.setOut(ps_console);
       System.out.println("Console again !!");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Mission failed, we'll get em next time");
    }
```

This method works fine if it is implemented in the program I want to redirect its output. In my case I want a separate class that will redirect the output of a certain program to a txt file.

If there is a simpler way to complete this task I am greatly inclined to hear.

Comment: How are you running the separate program?

Comment: Understandably, you may have a reason to change output in your program like this, but this isn't "best practice".  There are ways of capturing output from a program and placing it in files.  If you force your hand on the matter, it is no longer flexible (you couldn't, say, prevent it from writing to the file without recompiling the entire program).

Comment: If this is not intended to be a console program, use a logging mechanism such as log4j instead of printing to `System.out`.

Comment: `a separate class that will redirect the output of a certain program to a txt file` - a class cannot guide another to redirect console output, until the code written accepts the same(such as accepting the outputfile as execution arguments and act accordingly). Since this is a System property, this can only be set before execution starts. So, in your case, if code of the class-whose-output-needs-to-be-captured cannot be changed, there is no hope.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882772/capturing-stdout-when-calling-runtime-exec if you are able/want to run it as a separate process.

Comment: Why is this a stackoverflow question and not a softwareengineering one?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a perfect usage example for a logging framework.

- [SLF4J](https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html)
- [Log4J](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/)
- [Java Logging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html)

There are many other libraries you can use. In general it is always preferable to use a separate stream for files - if you *must* redirect `System.out` it could be useful to keep the original `PrintStream` before you change it so that you can still write to the console if you need to:

```
PrintStream ORIGINAL_SOUT = System.out;
System.setOut(ps);

System.out.println("ABC"); // Uses file
ORIGINAL_SOUT.println("ABC"); // Uses console
```

A simple usage example of a logging framework (from the first linked library):

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(YourClass.class);

logger.debug("A message at DEBUG level");
logger.info("A message at INFO level");
logger.warn("A message at WARN level");
logger.error("A message at ERROR level");
```

Comment: "redirecting System.out is a change you would have to revert every time you want output in your console." Could you not clone the stream instead, and still write it to the original console?

Comment: You mean by setting System.out to an extra PrintStream variable? Yes this is correct, I'll edit the question to reflect that. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create Temporary function for holding and storing your data with temporary and then execute your transactions anyway you want. Finally you can store your data wherever you want with permanently. This is the most known method I know. You should check the link for understanding easier.

http://www.daveoncsharp.com/2009/09/how-to-use-temporary-files-in-csharp/

Answer (score 0):

Logging software (such as SLF4J,Log4J etc)is better option.
It has different ways to create file,different  file formats, rolling appenders(based on dates/sequence/size), logs based on priorities